# How to find cord x&y in Array index?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I did move my coding to codepen, read there to see my script.
Just foccus on script file. Did use some templete and edit.

Update 2;
I wonder how to find both cordX and cordY in an Array.
Let's say we have Array like this;

```
const arr = [
//  -4  -3  -2  -1   0  +1  +2  +3  +4 <--X/Y;
    [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0], //-4
    [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0], //-3
    [1],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0], //-2
    [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0], //-1
    [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0], // 0
    [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0], //+1
    [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0], //+2
    [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0], //+3
    [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0], //+4
]
```

Example if I write: `arr[18]`
then it "should" give will give me;

```
cordX = -4
cordY = -2
let url= "https://codepen.io/sayok0/pen/abErgQx"
```

url is just link to codepen, can't write it open for some reason :/

- - 

I got how to find value inside INIT array, Thanks to "Ben Stephens".
But what I really want is to find cordX & cordY on current Array.

P.S!
arr is just some example, real code can you find on codepen.

Comment: Is it actually `[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]` (etc) or is it like `0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0` i.e. do you have a bunch of single element arrays or is that just a way to show that those are 'rooms' with values in?

Comment: @BenStephens, this is just to show for each room. Not sure yet how to code it in the best way. My plan is just to add 2 different methods. 1) Add a random room where there is number 0. And 2) set new room and connect it to other rooms. My final game project is to add it to the index.html file where the user can see the current room meanwhile all other rooms are hidden until discovered. Like a mini-game :) find the key to some random room, then go back to unlock some doors to get another key etc...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're after but this might be a way to get a room from coordinates:

```js
const room = {
    FLOOR: [-1,1],
    CORD_X : [-4,4],
    CORD_Y : [-4,4],
    ROOM : [
        {
            floor: -1,
            cordX: 2,
            cordY: 1,
            connected: [
                2,0,0,1
            ]
        }
    ],

    //0 = empty
    //1 = full
    INIT : 
    [
        [
    //  -4  -3  -2  -1   0  +1  +2  +3  +4 <--X/Y;
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0], //-4
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0], //-3
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0], //-2
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0], //-1
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0], // 0
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[1],[2],[0], //+1
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[3],[0],[0], //+2
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0], //+3
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0], //+4
        ],
        [
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        ],
        [
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        ]
    ],
};

const get_room = (rooms_data, { floor, cordX, cordY }) => {
  const floor_index = floor - rooms_data.FLOOR[0];
  
  const row_width = rooms_data.CORD_X[1] - rooms_data.CORD_X[0] + 1;
  
  const x_offset = rooms_data.CORD_X[0];
  const y_offset = rooms_data.CORD_Y[0];
  
  const room_index = (cordX - x_offset) + (cordY - y_offset) * row_width;
  
  return rooms_data.INIT[floor_index][room_index];
};

console.log(JSON.stringify( get_room(room, { floor: -1, cordX: 2, cordY: 1, }) ));
console.log(JSON.stringify( get_room(room, { floor: -1, cordX: 3, cordY: 1, }) ));
console.log(JSON.stringify( get_room(room, { floor: -1, cordX: 2, cordY: 2, }) ));
```

Edit: so if you want the coords for a floor index and you're happy using a function, you could use something like this:

```js
const room = {
    FLOOR: [-1,1],
    CORD_X : [-4,4],
    CORD_Y : [-4,4],
    ROOM : [
        {
            floor: -1,
            cordX: 2,
            cordY: 1,
            connected: [
                2,0,0,1
            ]
        }
    ],

    //0 = empty
    //1 = full
    INIT : 
    [
        [
    //  -4  -3  -2  -1   0  +1  +2  +3  +4 <--X/Y;
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0], //-4
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0], //-3
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0], //-2
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0], //-1
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0], // 0
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[1],[2],[0], //+1
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[3],[0],[0], //+2
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0], //+3
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0], //+4
        ],
        [
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        ],
        [
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        [0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],
        ]
    ],
};

const get_room_cords_from_index = (rooms_data, index) => {
  const row_width = rooms_data.CORD_X[1] - rooms_data.CORD_X[0] + 1;
  
  const x_offset = rooms_data.CORD_X[0];
  const y_offset = rooms_data.CORD_Y[0];
  
  return {
    cordX: (index % row_width) + x_offset,
    cordY: Math.floor(index / row_width) + y_offset
  };
};

console.log(JSON.stringify( get_room_cords_from_index(room, 18) ));
console.log(JSON.stringify( get_room_cords_from_index(room, 15) ));
```

Comment: thanks for this code, is useful :) Did update my post. Not 100% sure either so :P To make it short: I Want to add random rooms inside room.ROOM IF there is number 0 on that certain Array index on INIT, then add number 1 to that Array. I don't know, maybe I don't need INIT Array, and just check if it matches all 3 (room, cord_y, cord_x). I think I was trying to find Array index 75 examples, so instead of writing down all, I could then use INIT Array insteed.

Comment: Did update my topic again. My idea was to get both cordY and cordX from INIT Array. So If I write:  room.INIT[floor][18], then it would give me --> cordX: -4, cordY: -2.